# C bit manipulation DES permute

Tags: c, cryptography, bit-manipulation, bit, des

I was having trouble with implementing the DES algorithm in Python, so I thought I'd switch to C. But I've ran into an issue, which I haven't been able to fix in hours, hopefully you can help me. Here's the source:

```
 int PI[64] = {58,50,42,34,26,18,10,2,
                    60,52,44,36,28,20,12,4,
                    62,54,46,38,30,22,14,6,
                    64,56,48,40,32,24,16,8,
                    57,49,41,33,25,17,9,1,
                    59,51,43,35,27,19,11,3,
                    61,53,45,37,29,21,13,5,
                    63,55,47,39,31,23,15,7};

 unsigned long getBit(unsigned long mot, unsigned long position)
{
  unsigned long temp = mot >> position;
  return temp & 0x1;
}

void setBit(unsigned long* mot, int position, unsigned long value)
{
 unsigned long code = *mot;
 code ^= (-value ^ code) & (1 << position);
 *mot = code;
}

void permute(  unsigned long * mot, int * ordre, int taille )
{
 unsigned long res;
 int i = 0;
 unsigned long bit;
 for (i = 0; i < taille; i++)
 { setBit(&res, i, getBit(*mot, ordre[i] - 1)); }
 *mot = res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 unsigned long bloc = 0x0123456789ABCDEF;
 permute(&bloc, PI, 64);
 printf(" end %lx\n", bloc);

 return 1;
}
```

I made this permutation manually and with my Python program, and the result of this permutation should be `0xcc00ccfff0aaf0aa` but I get `0xffffffffcc00ccff` (which is, somehow, half correct and half broken). What is going on? How to fix this?

Comment: declare `unsigned long bloc = 0x0123456789ABCDEFUL;` note UL at the end

Comment: `-value` probably you mean `~value`

Comment: Step through it with a debugger, and notice when you can an incorrect value.

Comment: `1 << position` should be `1UL << position`

Comment: check that unsigned long is actually 64 bit, sometimes you need to use `unsigned long long`

Comment: Use `uint64_t` to get the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

I added UL at the end of my hex word, and I used uint64_t instead of unsigned long int. When I changed -value, I got either fffffffffffffff or 0, but with UL and uint64_t I'm getting the correct result, which probably means, as you guys suggested, that my unsigned longs were not 64-bit longs. Thanks !